# Check if string in one column contained by another?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a nested cluster analysis on some text data, using topic modeling approaches. In these approaches, overlap between "themes" (or topics) is allowed, to a certain extent. As such, I have some `identifier`s that have been grouped into multiple topics, while others have only been sent to one topic.

If you look below, you'll notice that several values for `level_3_id` have been "misplaced," so to speak (i.e. the value for `level_2_id` for that row indicates a different "level 2" theme than does the value for `level_3_id`. I'm trying to drop all rows in which the string in `df['level_3_id']` does not contain the string in `df['level_2_id']`, but am having some difficulties. See the code below.

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
       identifier level_1_id level_2_id level_3_id
15293  1270599    level_1   level_12  level_111
15294  1270599    level_1   level_12  level_122
15295  1270599    level_1   level_11  level_111
15296  1270599    level_1   level_11  level_122
15704  1269594    level_1   level_11  level_143
15705  1269594    level_1   level_11  level_111
15706  1269594    level_1   level_14  level_143
15707  1269594    level_1   level_14  level_111
29843  1271580    level_1   level_10  level_100
```

I'm trying to do something to this effect (I know it doesn't work, but I hope the general idea of vectorizing this string-containment checking processs is conveyed):

```
import pandas as pd

pairs = list(zip(df['level_2_id'], df['level_3_id']))
new_data = [y for x, y in pairs if x in y]
```

This basically gives me what I want, but is there a way to do this in `pandas` which avoids having to assign a shorter list to a longer `df`?

Something like this, maybe?

```
df['level_3_id'].str.contains(df['level_2_id'].str)
```

Edit:

A correct answer, after @Noobie's help below:

```
df[df.apply(axis = 1, func = lambda x: x['level_2_id'] in x['level_3_id'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['level_3_id'].apply(lambda x: x['level_3_id'] in x['level_2_id'].tolist())
```

Comment: I get this error, though: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: The update still doesn't work: `TypeError: string indicies must be integers`. Shouldn't that `apply` function be applied to the entire dataframe, not the series `df['level_3_id']`? Edit: even when applied to the entire df, the same error is raised.